# ValueError: Invalid version. The only valid version for X509Req is 0

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to renew the SSL but I got this error:

[image: SSL Error 1]

[image: SSL Error 2]

I already tried `sudo pip3 install pyOpenSSL` and sudo `pip3 install cryptography==40.0.1` and uninstalled it and installed it again, but it didn't work.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [cerbot GitHub issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/9717) from some other stack overflow network questions, which suggests that the issue was with `pyOpenSSL` [making a backwards incompatible change](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id6) when checking cert versions.

The certbot issue was fixed and released in 2.7.0, so if you do `pip3 install certbot==2.7.0 certbot-nginx=2.7.0` (and any other certbot packages you may have installed, I can't tell from the description), and rerun `certbot --nginx`, it should succeed.